# NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<Grease::Adapter(Less::Rails::ImportProcessor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce-rails

I have a strange error in my rails project. I use ruby 2.1.1@rails4.1.1 and recently added a gem "tinymce-rails".

Everything was working fine until this gem was added. I can't turn on my server in development mode nor production.

The error is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<Grease::Adapter(Less::Rails::ImportProcessor):0x0000000702fce0>
  (in /mnt/c/repo/intratur/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

Please help me!, I don't what to do!

Comment: Can you add the file being pointed? `application.css`

Comment: yes Sr. Recently a found a solution. The problem was with the version of the gem "less-rails". I change the versión to 2.6.0 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Grease gem dependency is only for "less-rails" greater or equal to 3.0.0. You can set the gem version to less than 3.0 to resolve it.

Reference: [undefined method `new' for #<Grease::Adapter(Less::Rails::ImportProcessor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825582/undefined-method-new-for-greaseadapterlessrailsimportprocessor/46826268#46826268)